# Weak factorization systems with right maps non closed under retracts

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, model-categories

Is there a standard name for the following flavor of weak factorization system?
I am interested in the data of two classes of maps $\mathfrak L$ and $\mathfrak R$ in a category $\mathcal C$ such that:

- $\mathfrak L$ is exactly the class of element having the left lifting property against all the elements of $\mathfrak R$
- $\mathfrak R$ is closed under pullback
- each morphism of $\mathcal C$ can be factored as an element of $\mathfrak L$ postcomposed with a element of $\mathfrak R$

So the main difference with actual weak factorization systems is that $\mathfrak R$ is not necessarily closed under retracts. I guess it is a notion that is fairly common (or at least the dual version, when dealing with cofibrantly generated model categories), but I have not been able to find a name for this in the litterature.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is that elements of $R$ can be called relative cocell complexes. As you say, most weak factorization systems used in practice are of this form, but the retract closure is so useful-for other purposes than construcying the factorizations-that it seems people usually just go ahead and close $R$ up under retracts.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks, that is more or less what I understood also. However, it seems that the notion defined in my post is a little different from the assertion that $({\vphantom{\mathfrak R}}^\perp\mathfrak R,({\vphantom{\mathfrak R}}^\perp\mathfrak R)^{\perp})$ is a weak factorization system, because in the latter the factorization of some $f$ as $pi$ can yield $p$ as only a retract of an element of $\mathfrak R$, while the former require $p$ to be actually in $\mathfrak R$. Or am I missing something that makes the two notions equivalent?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything.